# Rxjs 6 equivalent of Observable.create(subscriber -> {...}).share()

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I'm upgrading my Angular 5 app to Angular 6 and consequently from rxjs 5 to rxjs 6, I'm experiencing troubles in migrating the following piece of code:

```
const myObservable = Observable.create(subscriber => {
    // do something with the subscriber
}).share();
```

in particular I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.create(...).share is not a
>   functionTypeError: Observable_1.Observable.create(...).share is not

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to pipe share() as follows instead of chaining:

```
const myObservable = Observable.create(subscriber => {
    // do something with the subscriber
}).pipe(share());
```

Also make sure you import share as follows:

```
import {share} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
...
let obs$ = new Observable(...);
...
```

Above code should do the trick